# How to remove the carriage return at the end of a vi-copy in tmux

Tags: terminal, vi, tmux

I'm on OS X El Capitan and currently have the following lines in my `tmux.conf`:

```
setw -g mode-keys vi
bind -t vi-copy v begin-selection
bind -t vi-copy y copy-pipe "reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"
```

This lets me copy text from a tmux session with `<prefix>-y`. This works ok, except for the fact that the trailing carriage return often gets accidentally copied (thanks @sardorbek-imomaliev!) which results in commands being run before I'm finished typing them.

So my question (updated) is, how do I strip this carriage return automatically in case I have accidentally copied it?

Comment: carriage return is here because you copied it. You should copy till last character. Because when you copy whole line carriage return get included.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev: Oops, you're totally right. But it's a pretty easy mistake to make; perhaps a better question would be, is there way of stripping off this trailing CR in the event that it has been copied? (I'll also update the question to reflect this)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work :)

```
bind -t vi-copy y copy-pipe 'reattach-to-user-namespace tr -d "\n" | pbcopy'
```

But please feel free to correct me if if this is wrong or destructive in some way.

Comment: If you copy multiple strings it will merge them in one. So this solution will work only for single line copy.

Comment: This seems to work (without squishing everything onto one line): `bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe "perl -pe 'chomp if eof' | pbcopy"`. Of course, that requires Perl.